# Is there a way to get increment counter from a Python 'for' loop with decrement range?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I read everyone uses enumerate, but I don't think I know how to use it in my code. I want to print the value of an alphabet in a string according to alphabet order and the next character will increment the value by 1 and I want to start it from the last character in the string.

I can solve the code, but how can I replace the counter `i` without using `i = i+1` to make this code a bit shorter? Is there a way to implement something in the *for* loop?

This is my code:

```
    def project(r):
       i = 0
       for char in range(len(r),0,-1):
          print(ord(r[char-1])-96+i)
          i=i+1

    project(str(input()).lower())
```

For example, if I insert a string such as `"sad"`, the output will be `[4,2,21]` because `d = 4, a = 1, s = 19`.

Is there a way to implement the counter without initializing `i`?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question what I can understand is you want to use enumerate to get your result.

You can simply do as below:

```
def project(r):
    for (i, char) in enumerate(r, 0):
        print(ord(r[-i-1])-96+i)

project(str(input()).lower())
```

And the enumerate() method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of an enumerate object.

Syntax: `enumerate(iterable, start)`

Here `0` is the default value of start which you can give according to your requirement. For example, if you want your counter to start from `100`, then you can do like `enumerate(iterable, 100)`.

In the above code, I have used enumerate() function and initialized the counter from 0 and as you want to display from the last, I used `-ve` index to get the last item in a list.

And as I initialized the counter 0 so how can I get the items from last? For that, I subtract the index by `-1` like `r[-i-1]`. So for the first iteration the `i` value becomes `0`, so `r[-i-1]` becomes `r[-0-1]` which is `r[-1]` and on the second iteration, `i` becomes `1`, so `r[-i-1] becomes` r[-1-1]`which is`r[-2]` which result second last item. Similarly it goes on.

For more information about enumeration, please check the below link so you can get a clear idea.

1. *[Python enumerate()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate)*
2. *[13. Enumerate](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)*

Answer (score 0):

[Dcoder14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838890/is-there-a-way-to-get-increment-counter-from-a-python-for-loop-with-decrement/61839292#61839292), actually I want to make my code a bit shorter. Even there is a way other than enumerate, but still thank you very much... I used your code, but I edited it a little bit to make it one line shorter...

This is my code:

```
    def project(r):
        for (i, char) in enumerate(r, 0):
            print(str(ord(r[-i-1])-96+i))
    project(str(input()).lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it shorter, you can use the decrement char value since we can get an increment by subtracting the length of the string (input) with char in the *for* loop.

For example, this is my code:

```
    def project(r):
        for char in range(len(r),0,-1):
            print(ord(r[char-1])-96+(len(r)-char))
    project(str(input()).lower())
```

Comment: @anas ty for answering ill use yours